# How to get only Date from datetime column of type varchar(32) using linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a column in a table as PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME which contains value of the format 2016-01-09 14:06:19

But the column is of type varchar(32).

I have a linq query to compare PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME with a specific date alone. But it compares PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME with time.

> where (t0.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME.CompareTo(from_Date) >= 0) && (t0.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME.CompareTo(to_Date) <= 0)

Here from_Date and to_Date variable contains value like 2016-01-03.

So, I need to remove time portion from PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME.

how to write the Linq query for that?

Comment: Any chance you can store your dates as proper datetime2 objects in your db?

Answer (score 1):

you could parse the DateTime expression in PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME into a real DateTime and then use just the Date portion of that DateTime object.

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> dates = new List<string>();
    dates.Add("2016-01-18 12:05:12");
    string from_Date = "2016-01-16";
    string to_Date = "2016-01-18";

    var date = from d in dates where (DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null)
       .Date.CompareTo(DateTime.ParseExact(from_Date, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)) >= 0 && 
       DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null)
       .Date.CompareTo(DateTime.ParseExact(to_Date, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)) <= 0)
       select d;

    foreach(var d in date) {
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one. But while executing the query, getting this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: if you use entity framework, EF probably can't transform the ParseExact method into something the underlying database can execute. I don't know if there is a way to achieve that in EF. If there isn't, you could use EF to select a slightly broader range of records matching your from_Date and to_Date and then filter the non-matching records in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use EF to query this one.

So you should try

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime
```